# sql server split backups using powershell

Tags: sql-server, powershell, t-sql

I wanted to know the script for full database backup to multiple files depending on the size of the backup file. meaning split the backup file to multiple small backup files. please assist.

Comment: I would recommend instead you just come up with a standard like 4 or 8 or 16 files and adjust when that isn't enough. I don't know that there's a reliable way to know in advance how big a backup file is going to be given that empty pages aren't backed up and compression (which you should be using) can vary across the pages that are.

Comment: If you're trying to prevent more space from being used _before_ compression is applied, you can use trace flag 3042, but there is a performance penalty. See [this answer over on DBA](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/90366/1186).

Comment: Hi Aaron. thank you so much for your advise and suggestions.